# Running JavaScript code in a background thread in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a very intensive JavaScript code that is running in a webview.
Is there a way to run this code in a background thread to make the application responsive while this code is running.

I know that manipulating the UI must be made in the main thread but what about JavaScript code in a UIWebView?
Thanks in advance :)

***Edit:***
I'm not the one who wrote the JavaScript code. However it search in an HTML book for a text and highlight the text matched

Comment: Can you edit the JavaScript or just the Objective-C?

Comment: Any info on what are trying to do with the `intensive` javascript

Comment: you can now use Web Workers in mobile safari web apps.

Comment: Many Thanks. I have edited the post. I'll see if Web Workers will do the job :)